# ¿Cómo poner un Linear layout sobre un RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, axml

Ando empezando en el diseño de **Android**, y quisiera saber o me ayudaran a resolver éste problema, va a ser una tontería pero no tengo mucho en el diseño, necesito poder poner arriba del `RelativeLayout`, un `LinearLayout`, y no logro hacerlo, abajo anexo las imágenes para explicar el como quiero acomodar el Linear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="CERTIFICADOS"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar_obredetch_s" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Certificado Carterpillar"
                android:textSize="7pt"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Odebtreth | Lima, Perú"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/lblTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblTitle" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Me está quedando así:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi idea es que quede así:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes poner los dos `Layouts` dentro de un `LinearLayout`con orientación vertical.

Comment: @JesusPocoata, gracias, fue la solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón por la que cada elemento que agregas en el padre se vaya agregando hacia la derecha, es porque en el LinearLayout padre que lo contiene, defines la propiedad `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Esto hace que el `LinearLayout` decida agregar elementos de manera horizontal. Simplemente cambia la orientación a vertical.

Debes tener en cuenta que **"cada elemento hijo, comparte las propiedades generales del padre"**. Por ejemplo, los `LinearLayout` manejan propiedades como `weightSum`, `orientation`, etc... que no son manejadas por `RelativeLayout`, esto quiere decir que los hijos que definas en los `RelativeLayout` deben tener propiedades que sean propias de quien lo contiene. Digo esto porque veo que defines propiedades como `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` en hijos donde el padre no es un `ConstraintLayout`, por lo que no tendría ninguna funcionalidad.

Tu layout deberia quedar así, removiendo dichas `propiedades` y asignando la `orientacion`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Hijo del LinearLayout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <!-- Hijo del LinearLayout -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="CERTIFICADOS"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Hijo del LinearLayout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <!-- Hijo del RelativeLayout -->
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small">

            <!-- Hijo del ConstraintLayout -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar_obredetch_s" />

             <!-- Hijo del ConstraintLayout -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Certificado Carterpillar"
                android:textSize="7pt"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <!-- Hijo del ConstraintLayout -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Odebtreth | Lima, Perú"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/lblTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblTitle" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Hijo del LinearLayout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Andres, buenísima explicación